# We didn't find a server (A Record) behind your hostname XY

Tags: email

I have problem with my tester mail.

I got:
We check if there is a server (A Record) behind your hostname XY.

You may want to publish a DNS record (A type) for the hostname XY or use a different hostname in your mail software.

But in my reverse DNS I got:
FCrDNS test result:

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx resolved to xxxx;
xxx resolved to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
rDNS if forward confirmed.

Dynamic IP test result:
xxx not looks like dynamic IP address.

Please help